# Check is dirty for the gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am developing a web application where I am using a GridView control to load data from the database.

I have a row that is loaded in editable mode. I have a save button which the user clicks after making the changes, and I want to check the IsDirty flag to stop the user from saving and notify them via an alert box. I'm using a Web User Control (ASCX) to load the GridView. How can I check dirty rows in the grid and stop the user from saving when user clicks the save button or logout button??

P.S. I am using a LoginView for the logout button.

Comment: You need to provide more info. For example: How are you getting the data and binding it to the gridview? Are you using a SQLDataSource or you are using your DAL to retrieve and bind the data? Depending on the case, the answer to your question will be different. Post code if you can. Markup and Code Behind.

Comment: i am using a SQLDataSource to load the Gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the OnRowUpdating event in your grid, for example:

```
<asp:GridView id="a" runat="server" OnRowUpdating="a_rowUpdating" ... />
```

In code behind:

```
protected void a_rowUpdating (object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   //Add logic appropriately to know whether you should allow the update or not.
   //If you shouldn't, just set e.Cancel=true as below:
   e.Cancel=true;//will stop from updating.
}
```

You have access to the Old and New values in the `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` object. For more details and sample code, check [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple JS method to check for a variety of changes in ASP.net pages. I added it to a JS filer called CheckDirty.js and added a link to it on the page, in the file is this code:

```
var checkDirty = true;
var form_clean;
//this should be called when the save button is clicked, but prior to the page post
function onSave() {
    checkDirty = false;
}

// serialize clean form
$(function () {
    form_clean = $("form").serialize();
});

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if (checkDirty) {
        var form_dirty = $("form").serialize();
        if (form_clean != form_dirty) {
            return 'Your changes will be lost';
        }
    }
};
```

This will also work for changes to a gridview and will alert the user. I find this method best because it works with everything and I don't need to keep writing different methods for different controls.